# The webpage cannot be found after creating new site collection

Tags: site-collection, content-database

I created a new content database and then created a site collection.  When I try and access that newly created site collection, I get '`The webpage cannot be found' page.`  I am able to create new site collections on existing content databases.  Just having issues with newly created content dbs.  When I go to `/_layout/settings.aspx` (or any other .aspx) I just get a blank page.

Comment: couple of things to check....from central admin > application maanagement > view all site collections. check if you can see your created site collection as well as root level site collection "/"?

Comment: Went to 'view all site collections' and I do see that newly created site collection as well as the "/".

Comment: can you browse the root site collection? do you have issue only with the newly create site collection?

Comment: newly created site collection on newly created content db.  I can create a new site collection on an existing content database.  I noticed this issue yesterday.

Comment: root level site collection is in new Content DB or old?

Comment: it's old. i currently have approximately 35 site collections in this farm

Comment: how you creating the site collection? try to open the site from server? also try from different browser?

Comment: I've tried creating via Central Admin as well as using powershell.  Both with same results.  I've tried accessing the site from the server too.  Tried it using Chrome.  Same results.